# MarkerImage['size']

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

There are `MarkerImage`'s painted on a `StreetViewPanorama`. The scale at which each `MarkerImage` is displayed varies. Thus, the size of each `MarkerImage` is expected to differ. However, `marker.getIcon()['size']` returns identical values for each `MarkerImage` depicted. Any ideas as to the root of the discrepancy?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm really confused. Is this a phone/iPad app? Does U.S. 11 have anything to do with your question? What's 27, 37? Did you place the marker images? If yes, how? Show some code? How can I reproduce this scenario?

Comment: Are you saying that prior to the output shown you have set the `MarkerImage` sizes to other values that are being ignored or overridden in some way?

Answer (score 0):

The `MarkerImage.size` refers to the actual size of the underlying image (or in the case of a sprite, the size of the portion of the image). Streetview Panoramas distort the `MarkerImage` in order to show depth. The `size` property of the MarkerImage is not related to this distortion. Therefore, a MarkerImage object should ALWAYS report the same size.

To my knowledge, there isn't a way to get the currently displayed size of a marker through the API.